# Stepping in sbcl from within the debugger

Tags: debugging, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I am trying to figure out how to step through code in sbcl and Slime after invoking the debugger with something like break. I do not want to have to start stepping from the beginning. For example if I have the following code:

```
(defun fib (n)
  (when (eql n 2)
    (break))
  (if (<= 0 n 1)
      n
      (+ (fib (- n 1))
         (fib (- n 2)))))
```

After the break point is hit, I want to be able to start stepping through the code. The only way I have found to do this, is to go over the frame in Slime, use the "Return From Frame" (R) feature, and type in (step (fib 2)).

When I try to use the "Step" (s) feature, instead of actually stepping, I am given this:

```
Evaluating call:
  (CONTINUE)
With arguments:
   [Condition of type STEP-FORM-CONDITION]

Restarts:
 0: [STEP-CONTINUE] Resume normal execution
 1: [STEP-OUT] Resume stepping after returning from this function
 2: [STEP-NEXT] Step over call
 3: [STEP-INTO] Step into call
 4: [ABORT] Return to sldb level 1.
 5: [CONTINUE] Return from BREAK.
 --more--

Backtrace:
  0: (SWANK:SLDB-STEP 0)
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK:SLDB-STEP 0) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (EVAL (SWANK:SLDB-STEP 0))
  3: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK:SLDB-STEP 0) "COMMON-LISP-USER" 122)
  4: ((FLET #:FORM-FUN-7055 :IN SWANK::SLDB-LOOP))
  5: (SWANK::SLDB-LOOP 1)
  6: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::DEBUG-IN-EMACS))
  7: ((FLET SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGING-ENVIRONMENT :IN "/home/michael/slime/swank/sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::DEBUG-IN-EMACS) {1003DB44CB}>)
```

What I am looking for should be possible. From the sbcl manual stepping

> can be invoked via the `step` macro, or **from within the debugger**.

I am running sbcl 1.2.5 with Slime 2.12 and my optimization qualities are all 1 except for safety and debug which are both 3.

Comment: This is really out of context here, it sounds like a bug or a support request.  Have you tried asking in the IRC #lisp channel at freenode or SLIME's mailing list?  It doesn't seem directly about SBCL, as it doesn't seem you've tried stepping in it without SLIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had compiled swank with debug set to 3. Because of this, when I would step after the break it would then step into swank, giving the weird behavior described.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with trying to make the step debugging work since I started to learn common lisp. After reading this beautiful tutorial [debugging with slime](http://malisper.me/2015/07/07/debugging-lisp-part-1-recompilation/) I thought of giving the step debugger another chance...
This is what I did to recompile swank (read until the end before trying yourself):

Started a new sbcl session in a terminal:

```
rlwrap sbcl
ran the following
(declaim (optimize (debug 0)))
(asdf:load-system :swank :force t)
; then i noticed in the messages that it doesn't compile all the files
; compiling file "/home/smokeink/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-2.14/swank-loader.lisp"
; /home/smokeink/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.0-linux-x64/home/smokeink/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-2.14/swank-loader-TMP.fasl written
; then i tried:
(compile-file "~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150623.821/swank.lisp")
; compiling...
; ~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150623.821/swank.fasl written
```

That DID NOT work, so I went for another approach, I added this to swank.lisp:

```
; ...
(in-package :swank)
; added the following line
(declaim (optimize (debug 0)))
; ...
```

Restarted slime, it recompiled a few files, and THEN IT WORKED as expected.

(note that before doing the above, I had also changed

```
(declaim (optimize (debug 2)
                   (sb-c::insert-step-conditions 0)
                   (sb-c::insert-debug-catch 0)))
to
(declaim (optimize (debug 0)
                   (sb-c::insert-step-conditions 0)
                   (sb-c::insert-debug-catch 0)))
```

in swank/sbcl.lisp, 
but this change had no effect on the step-debugging problem)
(I had also tried to set `(declaim (optimize (debug 0)))` in .sbclrc and then to restart slime but as far as I can remember, that did not work.)

## Update:

> "After the break point is hit, I want to be able to start stepping
>   through the code. The only way I have found to do this, is to go over
>   the frame in Slime, use the "Return From Frame" (R) feature, and type
>   in (step (fib 2))."

You can actually proceed directly by pressing s ! No need to Return From Frame, just press s after the break took place. Note that for that to work you must have `(proclaim (optimize (debug 3)))` in your initialization file ( ex. .sbclrc)